# Event listener not working as expected for SVG path element click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

**How to detect either element or its children has been clicked.**

I have a parent element that contains multiple SVG icons, each with an attribute named `name` set to a specific value. I attached click event to parent element. And want to do some action if the clicked element is having attribute `name` equal to `setGameState`, it's not working as expected because sometimes the `event.target` points to the `path` element inside the `SVG`, so if condition is not working.

```js
const ele = document.getElementById("parent");
ele.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  console.log(target);
  if (target.getAttribute("name") == "setGameState") {
    //do other stuff
    console.log("svg with name setGameState clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" name="setGameState" data-gamestate="true" class="topbar-icon" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M12 22C6.477 22 2 17.523 2 12S6.477 2 12 2s10 4.477 10 10-4.477 10-10 10zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zM10.622 8.415l4.879 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1 0 .666l-4.88 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1-.621-.332V8.747a.4.4 0 0 1 .622-.332z"></path></g>
  </svg>
  <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" name="setGameState" data-gamestate="false" class="topbar-icon" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M12 22C6.477 22 2 17.523 2 12S6.477 2 12 2s10 4.477 10 10-4.477 10-10 10zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zM10.622 8.415l4.879 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1 0 .666l-4.88 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1-.621-.332V8.747a.4.4 0 0 1 .622-.332z"></path></g></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is described here:
https://gomakethings.com/detecting-click-events-on-svgs-with-vanilla-js-event-delegation/

It can be solved using the `closest()` method to look for a (potential) parent SVG element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Here I propose the variable `btn` that should contain the clicked SVG element or null, if some other element (like the parent DIV) was clicked.

Another (classic) solution might be putting the SVG in a separate file (mybutton.svg) an reference it in HTML using the IMG tag: `<IMG src="mybutton.svg" />`.

```js
const ele = document.getElementById("parent");
ele.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  let btn = target.closest("svg");    // <- get clicked SVG element
  console.log("target tag="+target.tagName+" btn.tag="+btn?.tagName);
  // check that user clicked an SVG element and it has the right name:
  if (btn && btn.getAttribute("name") == "setGameState") {
    //do other stuff
    console.log("svg with name setGameState clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="border: 1px solid blue;">
  <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" name="setGameState" data-gamestate="true" class="topbar-icon" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M12 22C6.477 22 2 17.523 2 12S6.477 2 12 2s10 4.477 10 10-4.477 10-10 10zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zM10.622 8.415l4.879 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1 0 .666l-4.88 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1-.621-.332V8.747a.4.4 0 0 1 .622-.332z"></path></g>
  </svg>
  <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 24 24" name="setGameState" data-gamestate="false" class="topbar-icon" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M12 22C6.477 22 2 17.523 2 12S6.477 2 12 2s10 4.477 10 10-4.477 10-10 10zm0-2a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zM10.622 8.415l4.879 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1 0 .666l-4.88 3.252a.4.4 0 0 1-.621-.332V8.747a.4.4 0 0 1 .622-.332z"></path></g></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: closest searches up the DOM tree, can we make it to search upto `parent` div only else return null

Comment: If you intention is to avoid catching some "random" higher-up SVG element, then I suggest you use classes to a) define which SVG elements are a button of certain class and <svg class="mybutton" ...</svg> b) use that class in the selector of closest(), like target.closest("svg.mybutton").

Comment: If you have other concerns, you could use the descendant selector in the closest() call, like target.closest("#parent svg.mybutton"). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator   However, it's not a given that this will result in better performance - better test, since complex selectors often perform badly (browser dependent).

Comment: Once again, you could also consider using an IMG element and either reference an SVG file or encode the SVG as data URI. That should not exhibit the issue of catching on the "path" element of the svg. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme  Programs like webpack can automatically convert image files to data URIs